# How can I check the custom protocol supports the opera via JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protocols

How can I check whether the custom protocol supports the opera via JS?

I'm using this code, but it does not work:

```
var iFrame = $('#hiddenIframe')[0];

try {
    iFrame.contentWindow.location.href = url;
} catch (e) {
    downloadFile();
}
```

Comment: What custom protocol? What does `downloadFile` do?

Comment: Protocol as mailto:
But allowing to interact with my application on the user's PC

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.